# Diff between two remote folders through SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, diff

Does anyone know how to list the files that exists in one remote folder and not in another remote folder. I have two servers (say Server1 and Server2) with similar folder structure where I'm doing Rsync. However, the destination folder has more files than the source as some of the files were deleted. Now I'm trying to find a way to find which files are new in Server2 by using `diff` between Server 1 and Server 2.

I can take the diff between two local folders directly using the following command:

```
diff /home/www/images/test_images /var/www/site/images/test_images
```

But I was wondering if it is possible to diff folders between two remote servers using ssh. Like this?

```
diff ubuntu1@images.server1.com:/home/www/images/test_images ubuntu2@images.server2.com:/var/www/site/images/test_images
```

Say the ssh configurations of Server 1 and Server 2 are as follows:

**Server 1**

```
IP: images.server1.com
User: ubuntu1
Password: pa$$word1
Images Path: /home/www/images/test_images
```

**Server 2**

```
IP: images.server2.com
User: ubuntu2
Password: pa$$word2
Images Path: /var/www/site/images/test_images
```

Hoping for any help to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: maybe :-) http://malcontentcomics.com/systemsboy/2006/07/send-remote-commands-via-ssh.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this command:

```
diff -B <(sshpass -p 'pa$$word1' ssh ubuntu1@images.server1.com "find /home/www/images/test_images -type f | sed 's/\/home\/www\/images\/test_images\///g'" | sort -n) <(sshpass -p 'pa$$word2' ssh ubuntu2@images.server2.com "find /var/www/site/images/test_images -type f | sed 's/\/var\/www\/site\/images\/test_images\///g'" | sort -n) | grep ">" | awk '{print $2}'
```

**Explanation:**

You can use `diff -B <() <()` for taking the diff between two streams. The command first uses `sshpass` to ssh into the two servers without having to enter your passwords interactively.

Each parameter for `diff -B` uses `find` command to recursively list all your images in the specified directory and uses `sed` to remove the root path of the files (because they are different for two servers - and to make it work for the `diff` command); and the `sort` command to sort them.

Since the output of the `diff` command returns either `>` or `<`, `grep` is used to filter out only the diffs from your Server 2. Last, `awk` prints out only the second column (removes the `>` column from the output).

**NOTE:** You need to install `sshpass` first. Use `apt-get` to install it as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install sshpass
```

You can extend this by piping other commands like `rm`. Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. You solved my problem, I just added a nohup 'you command' & disown to run in the background as it was taking a lot of time because I was testing on more than 1,000,000 images... great!!!